# How to implement a swift3 function with completion that wait for a passive function call? Like facebook sdk

Tags: swift, facebook, completion

I want to implement a swift3 function like facebook login api.
here is the sample code of facebook:(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/login)

```
@objc func loginButtonClicked() {
  let loginManager = LoginManager()
  loginManager.logIn([ .PublicProfile ], viewController: self) { loginResult in
  switch loginResult {
case .Failed(let error): 
    print(error)
case .Cancelled:
    print("User cancelled login.")
case .Success(let grantedPermissions, let declinedPermissions, let accessToken):
    print("Logged in!")
  }
}
```

See the function "loginManager.logIn" return a "loginResult" in completion block. And the login result should be created after the oauth call the sdk function in Appdelegate

```
public func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: 
[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(
  app,
  open: url as URL!,
  sourceApplication: 
options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String,
  annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation]
)
}

public func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, 
sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(
  application,
  open: url as URL!,
  sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
  annotation: annotation)
}
```

I've tried to use DispatchSemaphore in function to wait for the result.
but it blocks my main thread and makes my SafariViewController frozen.
Is there better solution to implement a swift3 function like facebook?

Many Thanks

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure if I understood your question, `loginManager.logIn` does not return a completion block, it actually receives a completion block as a parameter, as you can see on the Facebook documentation: 

`public func logIn(permissions:[ReadPermission]=[.PublicProfile],viewController:UIViewController?=nil,completion:((LoginResult)->Void)?=nil)`

Comment: Yes, but the loginResult in completion block should be created after function call in Appdelegate. I want to know how to implement this kind of function that wait for a result of passive function call.

Comment: Now I get it, this is the kind of things which is really nice to implement using RXSwift or something like that. =]

Answer (score 0):

I use DispatchGroup to solve my problem.
I call `dispatchGroup.enter()` in login function.
And put `onSuccess()` in `dispatchGroup.notify`.
And call `dispatchGroup.leave()`in another function which is called in Appdelegate.